# on which object is .addToUI invoked

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am new to javascript and to the google g-suite javascript programming; but have experience in software development (e.g. in vb.net).

I am trying to understand the following function definition, and in particular the last .addToUI() method.

My understanding is that SpreadsheetApp.getUI() returns a UI object on which .createMenu() is invoked. I guess this returns a menu object (i think), on which  .addItem() is then invoked, which probably returns a menu object as well, so how does the initial UI object receive the .addToUI() method.

much appreciating an explanation how the methods chaining works here.

thank you,

Dan

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Show alert', 'showAlert')
      .addToUi();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Menu`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/menu) object is constructed with knowledge about which [`Ui`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui) instance it came from, so calling `Menu#addToUi()` requires no arguments.

As far as chaining `Menu` methods like `addItem` and `addSeparator`, they effectively return a handle to the same underlying object data. That said, they do create a new object handle, so a strict equality between them will return `false`.
There are other chainable methods which do return a handle to a different underlying object, such as those that you might expect, e.g. methods like [`Spreadsheet#copy`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#copy(String)) - the handle is to the new underlying object, which is a deep copy of the original object and can be updated separately.

So to break it down, this function:

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .createMenu("some menu name")
    .addItem('title','function called')
    .addSeparator()
    .addItem('title 2', 'function called')
    .addToUi();
}
```

is functionally equivalent to the following:

```
function onOpen() {
  // Create a reference to the single Ui class that is active for the user this is running for.
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); 
  // Create a new Menu object, which knows which Ui instance it came from
  var menu = ui.createMenu("some menu name");
  // Bind a new reference to that same object by assigning the return value of the class method
  var sameMenuAsAbove = menu.addItem('title', 'function called');
  // Because these are object instance methods that mutate the object, they don't have to be chained
  sameMenuAsAbove.addSeparator();
  sameMenuAsAbove.addItem('title 2', 'function called');

  // Because 'sameMenuAsAbove' and 'menu' are references to the same underlying menu object,
  // calling 'addToUi()' from EITHER will result in the same appearance.
  menu.addToUi();
}
```

[The guide to menus](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus) may be helpful.

If you understand Python syntax, the Menu class could look like this:

```
class Menu():
  def __init__(self, ui, title):
    self.__ui = ui
    self.__title = title
    self.__drawn = []

  def addItem(self, caption, functionName):
    self.__drawn.append(Item(caption, functionName))
    return self

  def addSeparator(self):
    self.__drawn.append(Line())
    return self

  def addSubMenu(self, other_menu):
    self.__drawn.append(other_menu)
    return self

  def addToUi(self):
    self.__ui.add(self)
```

Comment: Great. thank you.

I also learned something new -- object mutation -- i.e. the java object is changed by the call while retraining its referent -- i guess.